# How do I split the dataframe based on dates in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, split

```
x1<- split(df, cumsum(df$Date < 1900-01-01))

x2<- split(df, cumsum(df$Date >= 1945-01-01 & df$Date <= 1955-01-01))
x3<- split(df, cumsum(df$Date > 2000-01-01))
```

I am trying to split the data frame based on the above mentioned conditions. However, the functions only work for the first one, not on the other two.

Here is what the data frame df looks like

```
 Date       T_min T_max
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1878-01-01   6.4  22.5
 2 1878-01-02   8.2  23.4
 3 1878-01-03   8.8  25  
 4 1878-01-04   8    24.5
 5 1878-01-05   7.8  22.4
 6 1878-01-06   7.9  20.8
 7 1878-01-07   7    21.5
 8 1878-01-08   7.7  21.4
 9 1878-01-09  10    18.5
10 1878-01-10   7.3  19.3
```

Comment: Can you show the df dataframe? I don't understand why you try to split on `cumsum`

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I have added the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this sample:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = c("1800-01-01","1950-01-01","2005-01-01"))
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(V1 = as.Date(V1))

          V1
1 1800-01-01
2 1950-01-01
3 2005-01-01
```

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(indic = case_when(
    V1 < "1900-01-01" ~ 1,
    V1 >= "1945-01-01" & V1 <= "1955-01-01" ~ 2,
    V1 > "2000-01-01" ~ 3,
    TRUE ~ 4
  )) 

list_of_df <- split(df, df$indic)

i = 1
MyF <- function(input){
  out <- as.data.frame(input)
  out <- out %>% select(-indic)
  nom <- paste0("dfE",i)
  assign(nom, out, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  i <<- i + 1
}

lapply(list_of_df, MyF)
```

This will create in your environment the dataframes `dfE1`, `dfE2` and `dfE3` based on the conditions you used first (about the dates).

```
> dfE1
          V1
1 1800-01-01


> dfE2
          V1
2 1950-01-01


> dfE3
          V1
3 2005-01-01
```

Comment: thank you. I tried this code. But I get the same problem. It works for the first condition but not the other two. 

I have added how the original data frame looks like in the question